# Where does "funk" and/or "funky" come from and why the musical reference?

Tags: meaning, etymology, music

Free your mind and your ass will follow - The Mothership has landed!! Why 'funk', of all words to describe such bootilicious music?

Comment: All funk and funkiness comes from George Clinton.

Comment: Whenever something is described as funky, I always ask, “James Brown funky or stinky cheese funky?”

Comment: For the same reason you would use "bootilicious" to describe it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funk#Etymology) on *Funk* indicates, Yale art historian [Robert Farris Thompson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Farris_Thompson) has posited an African origin to the musical use of *funky*. Here is an expanded quote from his 1984 work, *Flash of the Spirit: African and Afro-American Art and Philosophy*:

> The slang term 'funky' in black communities originally referred to strong body odor, and not to 'funk,' meaning fear or panic. The black nuance seems to derive from the Ki-Kongo *lu-fuki*, 'bad body odor,' and is perhaps reinforced by contact with *fumet*, 'aroma of food and wine,' in French Louisiana. But the Ki-Kongo word is closer to the jazz word 'funky' in form and meaning, as both jazzmen and Bakongo use 'funky' and *lu-fuki* to praise persons for the integrity of their art, for having 'worked out' to achieve their aims. In Kongo today it is possible to hear an elder lauded in this way: 'like, there is a really funky person!--my soul advances toward him to receive his blessing *(yati, nkwa lu-fuki! Ve miela miami ikwenda baki)*  Fu-Kiau Bunseki, a leading native authority on Kongo culture, explains: 'Someone who is very old, I go sit with him, in order to feel his *lu-fuki*, meaning, I would like to be blessed by him.' For in Kongo the smell of a hardworking elder carries luck. This Kongo sign of exertion is identified with the positive energy of a person. Hence, 'funk' in black American jazz parlance can mean earthiness, a return to fundamentals.

Answer (score 4):

*Funk* is actually quite interesting, because it is a back formation from *funky*, which in turn was formed from *funk*. As in, *funk* didn't just go from "bad smell" to "music genre" all by itself; it took a detour via the adjective form. Confusing, huh? Etymonline [explains it thus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=funky):

> *funky* "old, musty," in reference to cheeses, then "repulsive," from *funk* ["bad smell," 1620s, from dialectal Fr. *funkière* "smoke"]. It began to develop an approving sense in jazz slang c.1900, probably on the notion of "earthy, strong, deeply felt." *Funky* also was used early 20c. by white writers in reference to body odor allegedly peculiar to blacks. The word reached wider popularity c.1954 [...] and in the 1960s acquired a broad slang sense of "fine, stylish, excellent."

Answer (score 2):

*funky* originally meant *pungent* / *earthy*, with relatively positive associations to "passive" qualities such as the smell of a cheese, which just sits there mouldering away. Since being co-opted into jazz slang it's acquired the more "active" overtones of actual movement in the sense of *lively*, *rootsy*, etc. (funky music encourages dancing & foot-tapping).